# Как получить user id у Google Analytics и Яндекс.Метрика?

Tags: php, javascript, веб-программирование, google-analytics, yandex-metrika-api

Мне нужно идентифицировать пользователя на сайте. Варианты с IP или куками (и т.д.) хороши, но почти у всех динамические IP и разные браузеры.

Я узнал про такую штука как user id(Google Analytics) и yandexuid(Яндекс.Метрика).

Если правильно понимаю, user id это _gid(или _ga?) в куках. Почему этот ключ всегда разный на разных сайтах?

С yandexuid все проще, при работе с одного браузера все ок, но стоит добавить другой - ключ другой. Почему он не объединяет информацию про два устройства и т.д.?

Как правильно получать нужные мне данные? Какие еще есть варианты реализации подобной аналитики? 
Как вы решаете подобные задачи?

Answer (score 0):

Подскажу только со стороны GA.
Вы немного перепутали user id и client ID.
cID как раз таки генерируется самим GA в куки, при каждом создании куки он новый.
А userID вы отдаёте сами, его должен генерировать ваш сайт для авторизованных пользователей.

Здесь к идентификатору добавляется еще служебная информация для парсера, распишу, что какая часть означает:

- Первая часть (GA1) всегда такая и указывает версию формата записи
  идентификатора в cookie
- Вторая зависит от уровня домена, для которого
  установлена _ga, т.е. для доменов первого и второго уровней она равна
  1, для третьего - 2
- Третья представляет собой случайно
  сгенерированное число
- Четвертая показывает Unix Timestamp в секундах,
  когда Client ID был создан.

Тут хорошо описана основа cID https://burgerdata.com/blog/chto-takoye-client-id-v-google-analytics/

С yandexuid аналогично, насколько я помню, он создаётся для новых кук новый. Давно с метрикой не работал, для вебвизора использовал зачастую.

*Вот кстати, может решит вопрос, проброс cID в Метрику:*
http://prometriki.ru/kak-pometit-konkretnogo-posetitely-v-google-analytics-i-yndeks-metrike-cherez-google-tag-manager/
http://prometriki.ru/osobennosti-ispolzovaniy-client-id-google-analytics-v-yndeks-metrike/